# NSCollectionView dataSource not working properly

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'm experimenting with the new `NSCollectionView` API, introduced in El Capitan.

Following the WWDC video, I create a subclass of `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout` to determine the layout of the collection view.

```
class Layout : NSCollectionViewFlowLayout {

  override func prepareLayout() {

    super.prepareLayout()

    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 0

    let cheight = self.collectionView!.bounds.height
    let cwidth = self.collectionView!.bounds.width

    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cwidth / 2.0, cheight / 6.0)

  }

}
```

After that, I've created a `NSObject` subclass to serve as data source.

```
class DataSource : NSObject, NSCollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {

    /* DOESN'T GET CALLED! */

    let item = collectionView.makeItemWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    item.view.wantsLayer = true
    item.view.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor

    return item

  }

}
```

The **issue** is that `collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath:` never gets called.

This is how I initialise the collection view:

```
let collectionView = NSCollectionView(frame: view.bounds)

let dataSource = DataSource()
let layout = Layout()

collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
collectionView.registerClass(NSCollectionViewItem.self,     
                             forItemWithIdentifier: "cell")
collectionView.dataSource = dataSource

collectionView.backgroundColors = [.blackColor()]
```

I can clearly see the collection view in its superview, but there are no cells.

Also, this line, if called outside the delegate (but after the cell class is registered) makes the app crash!

```
let item = collectionView.makeItemWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: /*any index path*/)
```

Am I doing something wrong or is `NSCollectionView` new API broken?

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably a stupid question but you are adding the collection view to your view's subviews, right?

Comment: @Aaron I am. I can see the collection view in its superview (without cells)

Comment: how do you know the method was not called? did you set some breakpoint up inside that method? or tried to log something inside the method's body? is your `cell.xib` file in the same bundle? or do you create the interface programmatically (as you have registered a _class_ but not a _nib_)? have you changed the collection view's flow form _"legacy"_ to e.g. _"flow"_ in IB?

Comment: @holex I tried both. There are no .XIBs.

Comment: @MatteoPacini, you have _zero_ `.xib` file in your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating NSCollectionView with datasource programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230928/creating-nscollectionview-with-datasource-programatically)

Answer (score 0):

The method  *makeItemWithIdentifier* is crucial and looks for .xib named "cell" in you bundle: you may need register it with *registerNib:forItemWithIdentifier:* if it comes from another bundle.

Thus your problem comes before that, since your *collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath* never gets called and this could arise from your pattern: why do you create a new class to serve as datasource and not use the same NSViewController where the NSCollectionView resides?

I always do so and with the new API all works perfectly. Hope this could help you!

Comment: I'm trying to create the collection view programmatically, that's why I'm using `registerClass:forItemWithIdentifier:` rather than `registerNib:forItemWIthIdentifier`.

Comment: I've also tried both registerClass and registerNib without luck. numberOfItemsInSection gets called but itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem, and here is how I solved it.

First of all the problem I had :

- when my collection view delegate was NOT implementing the NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol, everything was fine and the collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath method was called
- when my collection view delegate was implementing the NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout protocol, collectionView:itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath method was NOT called

I commented out every NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method in the delegate, and it turned out that if the method collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection: was commented out, then everything was fine again (though I don't use headers).

It turned out that collectionView:layout:referenceSizeForHeaderInSection: was returning a NaN instead of 0.0 as the width in the size (stupid copy/paste mistake).

Are you sure you don't have the same kind of problem in what your layout is returning ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue I was having was that I didn't register either nib or class for the items of the collection view. The symptoms were exactly like those you describe -- `numberOfItemsInSection` was called, and `itemForRepresentedObjectAtIndexPath` was not. After registering a nib, the method started being invoked. Here's the relevant answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39516035/4635852